# Workfront API Custom Reports

Tags: attask, workfront-api

I am trying to access a custom built report through the WorkFront API. The issue I am running into is that the report prompts you for two pieces of information before running the report. Can I supply those pieces of information via parameters and have the API return the report?

example: /attask/api/report/[reportID]?input=value&input2=value2

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, however I don't think report through the API works that way at all. The report function in the API is used to get aggregate values. For example, you might want the average of the hours spent on a project. It is not a way to return the results from a report you created via the API.

The good news is that you can do the same thing super easy by just putting all your filters from your report into the query you build and then pass to the API.

Comment: Thanks, this seems helpful. Ill report back if I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there does not seem to be an API access point into the Reports and Filters used in WorkFront. The `report` functionality in the API is used for processing API results.

More information on API Reporting can be found [here](https://developers.workfront.com/api-docs/#Report)

Answer (score 0):

The report End point will not run the report it will only provide information on the report. You cannot run UI built  reports through the api you need to provide the logic within the API call itself.